# g++ on Debian:an updated compiler

Tags: g++, debian

I just installed Debian 6.0.7 and noticed that the "stable" branch comes with gcc 4.4.
I'd like to be able to use a newer compiler without totally switching to testing; is there something that would make this easier? I've tried compiling gcc a few times and it never went so well for me.
Mainly I want the code generation improvements, as well as the -Og option I read about, which applies optimizations that will not mess with debugging of code.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure apt to install select packages from testing while leaving the rest of the system on stable, and g++ should be something that you can handle that way without too much difficulty since g++-4.7 is a separate package that is simultaneously installable with older versions.

In brief, add:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 100
```

to either `/etc/apt/preferences` or a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`, which ensures that the packages aren't installed by default, and then add the wheezy repository to your `sources.list` file:

```
deb     http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main
```

and after an `apt-get update` you should be able to install g++-4.7.  Hopefully it won't pull in too many other packages.  You will then be able to use g++-4.7 as a compiler (without changing the default g++).